# Start vim with :browse old IF no file is specified as a cli argument

Tags: vim

I used to install vim-startify until discovering :bro[se] old.

How can I configure ~/.vimrc to :bro old if started with an empty buffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function BrowseOld()
    if @% == ""
       browse old
    endif
endfunction

au VimEnter * call BrowseOld()
```